# Postman - Response not rendered on preview tab of body - shows just a small thumbnail

Tags: postman

I have Postman request that returns a web page /url. I can see the source code of the page in the response. I know the request works. But when I click preview, I just see a grayed out thumbnail?
Any ideas why?
thanks in advance

Answer (score 4):

Postman is not a browser it doesn't load javascript and images as the content is loaded inside an iframe.

https://learning.postman.com/docs/sending-requests/responses/

you can see the errors by pressing ctrl+shift+i , as postman is chromium based it opens the chromium inspector where you can see the errors

[image]

if you want to see the full html then you can use **send and download** instead

[image]

this will save the content to your disk properly